# How to pass from python to C a list of differently sized arrays?

Tags: python, c, arrays, list, swig

In python (3.5) I have a list of N arrays each of different size. For N=2 for ex.:

```
v = [ np.array((0., 2., 4.)), np.array((0., 3.)) ]
```

Where N itself is not fixed.
From C I would like to access the n-th element of the i-th element of the list, e.g. v[0][1] = 2. .
As interface from python to C I'm using SWIG.

In C I have a structure like:

```
struct timestamps
  {
     int N;
     double **a;
     int *lengths;
  };
```

Where N is the number of elements in the list. 
I would like a to be an array of N places each containing the pointer to the n-th array of the original list. And lenghts to be an array of N places each containing the length of the n-th array of the original list.

For ex. in C I have a function that simply prints the value of the elements I want to access:

```
void print (int N, double **a, int *lenghts) {
    int i, j;
    struct timestamps T;
    T.N = N;
    T.a = a;
    T.lenghts = lenghts;
    for ( i = 0; i < T.N; i++ ) {
        for (j = 0, j < T.lenghts[i]; j++ ) {
            printf("%lf\t", *(T.a[i] + j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

I would like to call print from python script and obtain the output:

```
0.  2.  4.
0.  3.
```

My problem is that the native object is a list of numpy array that was created in python. 
What's the best way to do it? (I've done a couple of attempt but they're all "c - based" in nthe sense that I tried to create an array of pointer in python as I would have done in C but had no success)

Thank you so much I was really not able to find any "easy to understand for C person" reference...

Comment: Could you kindly share in pseudo code what it is that you intended to achieve in python and what your c file and interface file looks like?

Comment: Does the edit help???

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need an interface helper function. See [reference](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIG.html#SWIG_nn26)

```
    // Some array helpers
%inline %{
  /* Create any sort of [size] array */
  int *int_array(int size) {
     return (int *) malloc(size*sizeof(int));
  }
  /* Create a two-dimension array [size][10] */
  int (*int_array_10(int size))[10] {
     return (int (*)[10]) malloc(size*10*sizeof(int));
  }
%}
```

Also, your `a` needs to be a jagged array like this:

```
double *a[100];

a[0] = malloc(sizeof(double) * N1);
a[1] = malloc(sizeof(double) * N2);
```

Comment: Maybe I was not clear or I didn't understand you're answer... My point is not with C but rather on what is the object I should pass from python. How should I call from python a function that create in C my struct? I do not even need to allocate a[0] and a[1] since if I know their size i nC I'm perfectly able to navigate them without storinng more memory...